# android , is there any method to let service delay or sleep?

Tags: android

i need to let service sleep for 0.5 sec just as using Thread.sleep();

is there any method??

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes there is.  It's called [SystemClock.sleep(millis)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#sleep(long)).  There's also [Thread.sleep(millis)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)).  I suggest reading up on the differences.

Comment: Downvoted because of no explanation while OP is third result on Google for "thread sleep in android service".

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I think it's important to note (as has been said in other SO answers), that `Thread.sleep()` is not always good implementation for a background service, because it pauses the actual UI thread and not the Async thread.

Comment: @ytpillai how can it pause the UI thread in a background service? It's a _background_ service. It doesn't have a UI thread.

Comment: I just verified this. Calling `Thread.sleep()` does stop the UI thread, but so does `SystemClock.sleep()`. The proper way for this is to create a new thread, process everything in there (so also call `Thread.sleep` there).